# Load a HTMLImport (Polymer) when clicking a link <a onclick="...">

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, onclick

Let me say this, I've basic html and css skills, but unfortunately no js...

So, I'm trying to create one index.php which should import some html-content when clicking on a "link".

For each of my pages I've the same index.php, just one part is different. So why not just changing this part, instead of loading a different complete index.php ...

I'm using HTMLImports from Polymer for this purpose. I also tried jquery, but I didn't even get that far...

Here's my not working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,200italic,300italic,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="/favicon.gif" rel="icon" type="image/gif">
<link href="/imports/index.php" rel="import">
<link href="/static/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/static/js/polymer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>FOO</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><a href="/">FOO</a></h1>
<div id="nav">
<span class="right">
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/1.php')">1</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/2.php')">2</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/3.php')">3</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/4.php')">4</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/5.php')">5</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/6.php')">6</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/7.php')">7</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/8.php')">8</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/9.php')">9</a>
<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/contact.php')">// IMPRESSUM</a>
</span>
</div>
<hr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', function load(src, fn) {
        var link = document.createElement('link')
        link.setAttribute('rel', 'import')
        link.setAttribute('href', src)
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        HTMLImports.importer.load(document, function() {
            HTMLImports.parser.parseLink(link)
            fn(null, link.import.content)
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example of content from 1.php:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div id="img">
<style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">
    div#img { width:1570px; }
</style>
<img class="gallery" src="/img/01.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="01.jpg">
<img class="gallery" src="/img/02.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="02.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use HTML Imports for something like this but it might needlessly complicate things. You'll still need to write some JS that adds content from the import to your document. At that point, why not load iframes or even better, create a proper AJAX site?

The real benefit of imports is that the HTML parser can process the import while the rest of your app loads. However, if you're loading imports dynamically (instead of declaring `<link rel="import">`), that doesn't happen.

Here's a working example of your approach. It uses native Imports (

```
<a href="#" onclick="load('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/')">load articles</a>

<output></output>

<script>  
  function load(url) {
    var link = document.createElement('link')
    link.rel = 'import';
    link.href = url;
    link.onload = function(e) {
      var articles = this.import.querySelectorAll('article.tutorial_listing');

      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
      [].forEach.call(articles, function(art, i) {
        frag.appendChild(art.querySelector('h3'));
      });

      var out = document.querySelector('output');
      out.innerHTML = '';
      out.appendChild(frag);
    };

    document.body.appendChild(link);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! So, would I need to use jquery for this?
I'm not sure, but I could use the <a>-element, like in my example above?
And I think I'd have to change the querySelectors from your example? "article.tutorial_listing" and "h3"...

Comment: `<a class="nav" href="/" onclick="load('/imports/1.php')">ONE</a>` -- I'm not sure how to use those querySelectors. In fact, I want everything in the file "/imports/1.php" to be inserted in my index.php (so between <output> and </output>, right?)

Comment: `art.querySelectorAll('*')` would get you all the nodes in the article.